# subprocess.check_output works with import, not directly

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following in a .py file:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(['NET', 'VIEW'])
```

If I run the .py file directly by double-clicking on it, the window immediately shuts down.  It gives the following information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\working\script.py", line 2, in <module>
    output = subprocess.check_output(['NET', 'VIEW'])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'
```

However, if I pull up the Python console and run 'import script.py' it runs just fine.  How can I get this to run without importing it via the console?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed? Possibly one older than 2.7?

Comment: are there any other files in the directory that contains `script.py`? Is there a file named `subprocess.py` in that directory?

Comment: Python 2.7 and 3.2 are installed.
No other files reference script.py or are called subprocess.py.

Comment: Changed line 2 to:
`output = subprocess.Popen(['NET', 'VIEW'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]`

Now it works both ways.